# No Restore button for a custom shortcut

Tags: customization

It looks like, for 2.9, the *Merge* shortcut is <kbd>M</kbd> for everyone. In my case it is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, so I must have set a new shortcut. I've checked the *Preferences* for the currently selected keymap setting, and here is what I see (image below). As you can see there is no *Restore* button that would allow me to go back to <kbd>M</kbd>. Souldn't there be one? If I change it to <kbd>M</kbd> the *Restore* button will appear (but to go back to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>!). If I switch to one of the default keymaps in the top dropdown list I can find a setup where <kbd>M</kbd> is indeed the default setting. So I must be missing something here in the *Preferences* management.

**Edit:** So it looks like exporting and reimporting my own custom keymap (*whatevername.py* file) makes the new keymap its own default. Once this keymap is loaded there's no *Restore* button available to go back to some factory settings. If you create a new shortcut within this setting then the *Restore* button will appear, but to go back to *this* keymap default setting. I find it weird, there should be a way to go back to a default 2.9x keymap setting.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128134/discussion-on-question-by-moonboots-no-restore-button-for-a-custom-shortcut).

Answer (score 5):

So it looks like importing a given keymap (it is a .py file), will make this imported keymap its own default. There's no quick way to go back to a factory setting (or is there?). If you change one shortcut within this keymap, the *Restore* button will be available, but to allow to go back to *this* keymap original setting, as it was when imported.

Comment: the quick way back is - as Christopher proposed - just to set it to preset Blender settings, then it will be default again. Well - there is a "specific" kind of logic here, if you see it this way: if you save your keymap, you do this, when it is "ready" and "good" and your "default" and you want to use this keys. So this is your "new" default. If you e.g. now change your key from the imported again, you can restore it again to your saved version - which makes sense ;)

Comment: I will look into this, thanks for your help  ;)

Comment: Just as @Chris says, this logic here is, since this is a keymap you have saved and loaded (so it didn't destroy the default by overwriting it), this is your new default. And if you've spent a lot of time on it and are happy with it, I guess it won't make sense if you now try new shortcuts for some keys but don't like them, but restoring them will set them to the Blender default instead of your "custom default" which worked for you.

Comment: @ Gordon Brinkmann yes but sometimes it's hard to get Blender's logic  ;)  for example if you create a Diffuse node, change its color (or even don't change it), and want to bring back the default color with a right click > Reset to Default Value, it will load a black color (?!? it seemed to me that a 0.8 white color was the default value when I created this node). And so on...   ;)   it would be great to have a restore to basic 2.9 settings function

Comment: Yeah, the color default I don't understand either... I was puzzled by this as well. Maybe it's best to always create "default files" to come back to. A startup file that you save somewhere else, the default keymap saved separately and so on... so that you can load them all if something isn't restored as expected :D